# How to get a value of field in Krajee GridView?

Tags: yii2-advanced-app, yii2

How can i get value of ID in Krajee GridView?
I want to use id value in "onclick="get('.$ID.')".

```
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        'id',
        [
            'class' => '\kartik\grid\ActionColumn',
            'updateOptions' =>['style' => 'display:none'],
            'width' => '60px',
            'template' => '<a href="#" onclick="get('.$ID.');" >a</a>',
        ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use a callback realated to the button name

```
        ['class' => '\kartik\grid\ActionColumn',
            'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'width:34px; font-size:22px;'],
            'template' => '{update}',               
            'buttons' => [
                'update' => function ($url, $model) {
                    return   '<a href="#" onclick="get('.$model->id.');" >a</a>';
                },
             ],
        ]
```

Comment: you should remove one return
you use 2 return's

Comment: @AbdallahAwwadAlkhwaldah   correct ... thanks  ... double return removed .. many thanks  .. again